# android soft keyboard not showing on button click

Tags: java, android

**Here is the method on buttonclick but it is not working... i have tried many things but nothing seems to be work**

```
public void open_keyboard(View view)
{
    message.msg_l(this, "keyboard clicked");
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of view?

Comment: Do your button click called properly?

Comment: yes it does... because it generates a toast on screen with a message "keyboard clicked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this,

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(MainActivity.this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mainLayout.getWindowToken(), 0);
```